# notification expiry product in vb.net with ms access

Tags: vb.net

I just wanted to ask on how to notify a product on or before its expiry date in vb.net. I tried a lot of codes about it but still i am not able to solved this problem. I will really appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: Show what you tried so far..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didnt provide the table structure, I will try to help you understand the logic, which you can easily apply to your table.

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   tbproducts
WHERE  Datediff(d, now, tbproducts.expiarydate) > 0
```

Here you are simply saying, "please count for me how many products (rows) that passed their expiration day, when compared with right now"

`Datediff(d, now, tbproducts.expiarydate)` Will subtract today's date `Now` from the product's expiry date, and return the difference (in days `d`). This will return a `long` number.

So the difference between 12/7/2017 (now) and 12/5/2017 (expired 2 days ago), will be 7 (7th) - (minus) 5 (5th) = 2

And the difference between 12/7/2017 (now) and 12/10/2017 (not yet expired), will be 7 (7th) - (minus) 10 (10th) = -3

So as long as `Datediff(d, now, tbproducts.expiarydate)` returns a number over 0 then the product is expired